# How to make high score save in game? xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making a small game for iOS in Xcode. In my game, tapping on a dot will give you one point. I am trying to make it so that if your score is higher than the first high score(0), it should save that and display the new high score. And the next score can beat that, and so on. Please give a thorough explanation because I am new to xCode and I am a 12 year old app developer.

Comment: Look into using `NSUserDefaults` and/or `NSFileManager`.

Comment: This is the wrong site to ask for descriptions of how to do things. You come here with specific questions about things you're stuck on. Here's something that should help you with your problem: http://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2 And good luck! :)

Comment: @Almo Thanks! Someone else answered, and I will try their method, but thanks for the friendly comment! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSInteger HighScore;
int Score;
IBOutlet UILabel *Show;

-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
HighScoreNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
}

-(void)ShowHighScore
{
if (Score > HighScore) {
        HighScore = Score;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScore forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
    }
Show.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", HighScore];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your **do not** find your score data important or sensitive use `NSUserDefaults`

**First scene: *(Setting the integer)***

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:yourHighScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

**Other scenes: *(Getting the integer)***

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
yourHighScore = [defaults integerForKey:@"HighScore"]
```

**Or same scene setting the `yourHighScore` value: *(Getting the integer)***

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    yourHighScore = [defaults integerForKey:@"HighScore"]
}
```